# Using a global object or parameters to pass config data, which one is better in Scala?

Tags: scala

I'm newbie to Scala, and I have years of experience programming in Java.

Usually there are two patterns passing some config:

- Using a global object sounds like "ConfigManager". And every time I
  needs a config I get directly from it.
- Passing the config through parameter. The config param may exists in
  many layers in the program.

I choose one pattern depends on how the config will be used when I'm writing Java.

But in Scala, many people talks about eliminating side effects. This makes me wonder if I should use the second patterns at any costs.

Which pattern is better in Scala?

Comment: I would suspect what using companion object will solve lots of problem : http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/singleton-objects.html

Comment: For reference: the `Reader` monad (provided by Cats or Scalaz) can simplify the second pattern, but that may be a little advanced if you're just starting with Scala.

Comment: There's a few. `Reader`, `Free`, `@Inject` via guice or similar, ...

Comment: @PeterNeyens Thanks for your suggestion! After I saw your comment, I have read some posts about Reader monad. I think I understand how to use it now. But I also think using it to pass a global config which contains values of different aspects may not be a good idea. This may cause carrying too much configs into lower level of the program, or I should cut the config on the way which making programming more tricky. Anyway, I will write some code using Reader monad, and see what's going on.

Comment: @AndrewLi Most of the `Reader` implementations have some kind of `local` function, which allows you to go from a global config to a local config, see for example the last example in the [cats documentation for `Kleisli`](http://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/kleisli.html) (`Reader[A, B]` is equal to `Kleisli[Id, A, B]`).

Comment: @AndrewLi Here is the answer, I have undeleted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use global object (this object stores only read-only immutable data, so no issues) which loads configuration object and config variables at once. This has many benefits over loading the configuration deep inside the code.

```
object ConfigParams {
  val config = ConfigFactory.load()
  val timeInterval = config.getInt("time_interval")
  ....
}
```

Benefits:

1. Prevents runtime errors (Fail fast approach).

   If you have miss spelt any property name your app fails during startup as you are trying to fetch the data eagerly. If this were to be deep inside the codebase then it would be hard to know and it fails when the control of the program goes to that line. So, it cannot be easily detected unless rigorous testing is done.
2. Central place for all configuration logic and configuration transformations if any.

   This serves as a central place for all config logic. easy to change and maintain.
3. Transformations can be done without need for refactoring the code.
4. Maintainable and readable.
5. Easy refactoring.

*Functional programming point of view*

Yes, loading the config file eagerly is great idea from Fail fast point of view but its not a good functional programming practice.

But important thing is you are not mixing the side effect with any other logic and keeping it separate during the loading of the app. So, as you are isolating the side effect and side effecting at the starting of your project, this would not be a program.

Once the side effecting is done and app has started. Your pure code base will not effected from this and remains pure and clean. So, though it is side effecting, it is isolated and does not effect your codebase. Benefits you again from this are worth experiencing, So go ahead.

Comment: This is not fail-fast, as object initialisation happens at first request for a field from the object, this may not be at the actual point of startup (e.g. if you were using Guice DI with Play, this would probably fail at first request, if that was where the value was needed).

In addition, object initialisation can then fail, and future references will fail to find the class. This extreme failure mode can be slightly ameliorated by making potentially failing field definitions into `lazy val`.

Also, this is unavoidable singleton state, which is inflexible (e.g. hard to use when testing).

Answer (score 6):

Global objects are bad: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil

Make each component take it's configuration (individual pieces) as constructor parameters (possibly with some defaults). That prevents the creation of invalid components or components that have not been configured.

You can collect the initial processing of configuration values in a single class to centralize configuration code and to fail-fast when things are missing. But don't make your components (classes needing the configuration) depend on a global object or take in an entire configuration as a parameter. Just what they need as constructor params.

Example:

```
// centralize the parsing of configuration
case class AppConfig (config: Config) {
  val timeInterval = config.getInt("type_interval")
  val someOtherSetting = config.getString("some_other_setting")
}

...
// don't depend on global objects
class SomeComponent (timeInterval: Int) {
  ...
}

object SomeApplication extends App {
  val config = AppConfig(ConfigFactory.load())

  val component = new SomeComponent(config.timeInterval)
}
```